# Bootstrap glyphicon not rendering properly in safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap glyphicon for username and password. It is rendered properly on all browsers except on safari. I have attached the snapshot below. I am not able to figure out what is the issue. I have tried making the font size small`(style="font-size:x-small")` and using the `<small></small>` tag, but I am still not getting the result. 
Here is the code:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">

<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user red"></i></span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
</div>
```

[image: login via safari]

Comment: have you visited this link? its already some asked on their github repo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106

Comment: @IsmailFarooq thanks but I am not able to follow what they have discussed there

Comment: by the way which version are you using of bootstrap?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I am using 3.3.6

Comment: Have u try by updating ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq since it is an official web application I do not have the permisiion to update the nuget packages

Comment: I don't why its not working if u see bootstrap example its working fine there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107638/discussion-between-ismail-farooq-and-sumedha).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using old version of bootstrap try by updating `glyphicon` see this [Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106) might solve your problem